# Docker compose fails with error `failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)`

Tags: docker-compose, windows-container

I have a docker compose file that looks like this

```
version: '3'

services:
  mongodb:
    container_name: mongodb
    restart: always
    image: mongo:4.2.22
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
  webapp:
    container_name: webapp
    image: webapp:1.0
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: WebApp
```

I can run the command `docker-compose up -d --build` and read/write from the Mongo db. But if I change the DockerFile to be

```
version: '3'

services:
  mongodb:
    container_name: mongodb
    restart: always
    image: mongo:4.2.22
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
  webapp:
    container_name: webapp
    image: webapp:2.0
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: WebApp
```

and run the aforementioned command, the build completes successfully but I do get the error

```
ERROR: for webapp
Cannot start service webapp: container <container-id> encountered an error during hcsshim::System::CreateProcess: 
failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)
```

The code between `v1` and `v2` is very similar except in `v2` I create a couple of new databases. If I switch my `docker-compose` file to use `v1` the containers come up just fine. Curious as to what is causing the error and was wondering if anyone had some suggestions.
`docker logs <containerid>` does not show anything either.

Thank you

Comment: When both `image` and `build` are specified docker-compose will try to pull the image first and if it's not found then build it. Could you please check if `webapp:2.0` image is present in registry? Also please check if `Dockerfile` is present in the current directory.

Comment: Also you can check if an image can be built from this `Dockerfile` with `docker build`

Comment: Hi @MikeMozhaev, both `webapp:1.0` and `webapp:2.0` exist in my local registry.

Comment: Will `webapp:2.0` run successfully if you start it with `docker run`?

Comment: If I do a `docker run --name test -d webapp:2.0` I get the `The System cannot find the file specifed`

Comment: Please check what you have specified for `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` in `Dockerfile` for `webapp:2.0`